# SharePoint/Angular can't delete item - Error 412

Tags: angularjs, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

**Update:** I have changed my Services and Controller as follows and am now receiving an Error 412 (HTTP/1.1 412 Precondition Failed). Here is my updated code:

Service:

```
appServices.factory('appType', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Todo Types List')/Items(:Id)", { Id: "@Id" },
    {
        'query': { method: "GET", isArray: false, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'update': { method: 'PATCH', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'save': { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() } },
        'delete': { method: 'DELETE', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() }, 'IF-MATCH': "*" },
    }
    );
}]);
```

Relevant part of Controller:

```
$scope.removeType = function (type) {

appType.delete({ Id: type.Id });
console.log("Deleted" + type.ID);
}
}]);
```

**Original Post:**

I am attempting to delete an item/row in an Angular App built on top of SharePoint 2013, but when I am attempt the delete it appears to process, except nothing is removed from the SharePoint list. Using the network tab in IE, I get a 400 error.

Here is my controller:

```
appControllers.controller('appSettingsCtrl', ['$scope', 'appTypes', function ($scope, appTypes) {

// Retrieve Types
$scope.types = [];


appTypes.query({}, function (data) {
    $scope.types = data.value;
});


// Create Types
var typeEntry = new appTypes;

$scope.addType = function () {
    console.log("Clicked");
    typeEntry.Title = $scope.itemtype;
    typeEntry.$save();
}

// Delete types
$scope.removeType = function (type) {

appTypes.delete({}, { Id: type.ID });
console.log("Deleted" + type.ID);
}
}]);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="type in types" id="type{{type.Id}}">

            <td>
                {{type.Title}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="removeType(type)">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my service:

```
   appServices.factory('appTypes', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Todo Types List')/Items", {Id: "@Id" },
    {
        'query': { method: "GET", isArray: false, headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'update': { method: 'PATCH', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' } },
        'save': { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() } },
        'delete': { method: 'DELETE', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), 'IF-MATCH': '*'  } },
    }
    );
}]);
```

Here is some sample JSON:

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 5,
        "ID": 5,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x01004CE051F4BDBACB43BB22C234F8F497FE",
        "Title": "Type 1",
        "Modified": "2015-03-13T18:35:09Z",
        "Created": "2015-03-13T18:35:09Z",
        "AuthorId": 12,
        "EditorId": 12,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "9ceee022-a418-43d4-86b1-1de6d68edc47"
        }
   ]
}
```

Comment: have you captured any packets using something like Charles to see what is happening behind the scenes?  That will tell you a lot.

Comment: Not yet, I am digging through POSTMAN and seeing an 403 Forbidden

Comment: Why are you passing `{ Id: type.ID }` as the second parameter to `.delete()`? Shouldn't it be the first parameter?

Comment: I was following the booking example here: http://www.masnun.com/2013/08/28/rest-access-in-angularjs-using-ngresource.html Digging deeper, I am now getting a 400 error once I add the header of 'IF-MATCH': '*'

Comment: This is also an example I was following (see answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269882/angularjs-resource-restful-example

Comment: On the "IF-MATCH" issue, you need to make sure that your server supports it.  On the 400, make sure that the server is getting the parameters it's expecting.  As JLRish mentioned, try changing this:

appTypes.delete({}, { Id: type.ID });

to

appTypes.delete({ Id: type.ID });

Comment: See example here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17376890/angular-js-full-example-of-get-post-delete-put-client-for-a-rest-crud-backend

Comment: On last comment - if you are going to use REST with Angular, you should really be using this if you can:  https://github.com/mgonto/restangular - it takes the pain out of rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using following headers when removing a item from a list.

```
 "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
 "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
 "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
 "If-Match": "*",
 "X-Http-Method": "DELETE".
```

For me it works. Hope it helps to you too.

Answer (score 0):

Blame this error on having a small typo that malformed the header (The If-Match was outside of the headers:. This is correct:

```
'delete': { method: 'DELETE', headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose', 'X-RequestDigest': $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(), 'IF-MATCH': '*' } }
```